# Sobre o método onActivityResult() no Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Boa tarde pessoal, tenho um trabalho para entregar feito no Android Studio, estava tentando mandar Strings por intents, meu professor disse que a forma correta seria utilizando o startActivityForResult() e o OnActivity(), porém parece que as Strings não estão sendo enviadas, tentei mudar de várias formas.Podem me ajudar?

**Código Activity enviadora**

```
            btArmazenaDisco.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            estilMusica = EstiloMusical.getText().toString();
            alb = album.getText().toString();
            artist = artista.getText().toString();

                quantmusic = quantmusica.getText().toString();

                 // enviando os itens
                   Intent intentEnviador = new Intent(CriarDiscoActivity.this,Activity_Pastas.class);
                   Bundle informacao = new Bundle();



                    informacao.putString("addestilMusica",estilMusica);
                    informacao.putString("addAlbum",alb);
                    informacao.putString("addArtista",artist);
                    informacao.putString("addQuantiMusica",quantmusic);

                    intentEnviador.putExtras(informacao);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK,intentEnviador);


                   startActivityForResult(intentEnviador,Constante_Activity_Pastas);


            }
```

**Código Activity Recebedora**

@Override

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if(resultCode==CriarDiscoActivity.RESULT_OK && requestCode== CriarDiscoActivity.Constante_Activity_Pastas) {

        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
        if(bundle!= null) {


            estiloMusica = bundle.getString("addestilMusica");
            Album = bundle.getString("addAlbum");
            Artista = bundle.getString("addArtista");
            QuantMusica = bundle.getString("addQuantiMusica");

                //Testando para ver se foi enviado
                test.setText(estiloMusica);
            Toast.makeText(this, estiloMusica, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //
            musicas.add(new Musica(estiloMusica, Album, Artista, QuantMusica, 0));
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Coloque o código como texto formatado aqui, não use imagens para compartilhar código

Comment: Pronto, coloquei o código, obrigado por avisar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que você está confundindo algumas coisas. A **mesma** activity que usa `startActivityForResult()` deve implementar o método `onActivityResult()`.

**Activity Inicial**

```java
btArmazenaDisco.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    Intent intentEnviador = new Intent(CriarDiscoActivity.this, Activity_Pastas.class);
    Bundle informacao = new Bundle();

    informacao.putString("addestilMusica",estilMusica);
    informacao.putString("addAlbum",alb);
    informacao.putString("addArtista",artist);
    informacao.putString("addQuantiMusica",quantmusic);
    intentEnviador.putExtras(informacao);

    // Aqui você iniciará a Activity "Activity_Pastas"
    startActivityForResult(intentEnviador,Constante_Activity_Pastas);
}
```

```java
// Aqui você receberá o retorno da Activity "Activity_Pastas", caso tenha algum.
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == Constante_Activity_Pastas) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            // Faça algo
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity Chamada**

```java
// Código para receber a informação passada
Intent recebido = getIntent()
String estilMusica = intent.getStringExtra("addestilMusica");
String alb = intent.getStringExtra("addAlbum");
String artist = intent.getStringExtra("addArtista");
String quantmusic = intent.getStringExtra("addQuantiMusica");

// Código para encerrar a Activity e avisar a Inicial (que está esperando pelos resultados)
Intent intent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Repare que no exemplo eu não passei nenhum `Extra` da Activity Chamada para a Activity Inicial, mas isso pode ser feito colocando os `Extras` no `Intent` e recebendo no `onActivityResult`.

Em ordem, ocorre:

1. Clique no botão -> `startActivityForResult()`;
2. `Activity_Pastas` é criada;
3. Você faz o que precisa na `Activity_Pastas`, recebe os dados com `getIntent()`;
4. Avisa que está encerrando a `Activity_Pastas` com `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)`;
5. Encerra a `Activity_Pastas` com `finish()`;
6. `onActivityResult()` é chamado na Activity principal com `requestCode == Constante_Activity_Pastas` e `resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK`.

Comment: Ah então o onActivityResult() é colocado na Activity que estou enviando os itens, meio que para confirmar esse envio?

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Sim, não exatamente para confirmar o envio, mas para receber algo de volta. Por exemplo, você iniciou a segunda activity e quer um intent de retorno com algum dado. Se você não quiser o retorno, você pode usar só `startActivity`, na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity) tem uns exemplos

Comment: Só uma dúvida, meu professor pediu para adicionar esse método, o que eu estou fazendo é apenas enviando dados para adicionar em uma list view, pode me dar um exemplo do que fazer dentro desse método?

Comment: Do que fazer dentro do `onActivityResult`? Sem ter o contexto geral da aplicação, não dá pra saber, mas me parece que você não precisa fazer nada ali, Fica até difícil de dar um exemplo, mas de modo geral é quando a sua `ActivityUm` precisa de algum retorno da `ActivityDois` para atualizar a interface.

Comment: Entendi, muito Obrigado.

Comment: Tipo minha activity principal(a que abre quando inicio o aplicativo) é a da List View, ai eu entro nessa para armazenar os dados de um disco, depois volto nela novamente.

Comment: Você pode usar o `onActivityResult` para exibir um [`Toast`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts) escrito "Dados armazenados", por exemplo

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado.